# Critique this strategy

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, gridview

I want to populate a gridview by using jQuery and AJAX.  From my calling page jQuery will call a handler (.ashx) that will deliver XML data or HTML markup for the gridview. As I see it I have two choices: 1) deliver XML which is then bound to the design-time gridview on the calling page, or 2) deliver HTML for the gridview.  My first question is: which method is easiest?

Now there are two factors which complicate things. First, the gridview must be sortable on all columns.  Second, the data will be filtered (some columns will be hidded) by user configuration options which are also to be stored in the database.  Knowing this, does your answer to the first question change?

Any comments, insights or gotchas are appreciated.

Dewey

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using ASP.Net Ajax with an update panel around your gridview?  Seems like the easiest way to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something very similar to this on a recent project.  I used jqGrid for display purposes - it can easily be bound to JSON-formatted data (and probably XML-formatted data too), and it supports click-column-header-to-sort.  I would definitely recommend it for functionality and ease-of-use.

I didn't have to implement user-configurable showing/hiding of columns.  However, it could be done with jqGrid pretty easily: the grid columns are configured in javascript, so you could use code-behind logic during the initial page-build to customize the javascript which defines the column configuration.

I definitely wouldn't return HTML from an ASHX class, since you'd have to craft all the HTML by hand using StringBuilder (or something similar).  Makes the code tougher to maintain; and if you ever want to change the page layout, you need to re-compile and re-deploy your system.  If you desperately want to return fully-formatted HTML, I would probably use jquery/ajax to just call a .ASPX page.  That approach is clunky and heavy-handed - but at least .ASPX is geared toward generating full HTML, unlike .ASHX.

You might want to consider returning JSON instead of XML.  It makes for smaller, faster responses over the wire, and is amazingly easy to work with, within javascript.  In that case, you should consider using ASMX instead of ASHX to generate the JSON, since it can be configured to automatically serialize your returned object as JSON.  That's what I did on my project, and it was very fast and easy to develop.

Finally, I **VASTLY** prefer jquery and ajax to Microsoft's ajax and updatePanels.  [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289839/is-there-a-reason-to-prefer-jquery-ajax-to-asp-net-updatepanel) details the reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

I think delivering HTML is easier.
But I choose delivering XML to dynamically sort and filter data by using a javascript rendering function like:
function render(options) {

}

The options parameter will be an object that stores orderby parameter and hidden column names such as:
options = {orderby:"name", hidecolumns:["surname", "age"]};

I hope that helps.